# Standards-compliant equivalent to target="_blank"

Tags: jquery, html, strict, new-window

There are instances where I have to open links in a new window/tab. Is there a method of doing so that is valid for strict HTML? Using jQuery to do so would be acceptable, but I'd rather not just sneak the `target="_blank"`s back in w/ jQuery so that validators won't see them.

Comment: Here's a handy flowchart to help you know when to use target="_blank": http://t.co/gfKZiXt

Comment: @jerone: That's pretty funny, but not actually helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry, just got this tweet today. Ontopic: don't know of any valid method for this; jQuery seems the best alternative.

Comment: The sanest things I've seen involve setting `rel="external"` and using JavaScript to enforce it. But why don't you want to use `target`? Are you using the XHTML Strict doctype? Because if you're using HTML5, `target` is actually valid.

Comment: @jerone: No need to apologize... it *was* funny.
@sdleihssirhc: I hadn't realized it had become un-depreciated... unfortunately I think our user base may still be a bit too entrenched in IE7 to use HTML5 yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you said jQuery is allowed.

```
<a href="http://mysite.com" class="newWindow">Open in new window</a>

$('a.newWindow').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   window.open(this.href);
});
```

You could also do this via normal JS. This way your HTML won't have `onclick` peppered all over the place.

EDIT - Updated to use `e.preventDefault()` as per Ian's suggestion.

Comment: `each` -> `click`? `return false` -> `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Also `'` -> `"` for the sake of proper HTML.

Comment: I think you mean $('a.newWindow').click(...)

Comment: @ates @Abdullah fixed! thanks guys, it's the tailend of a _really_ long day :)  `return false` prevents default and stops propagation so it works well

Comment: @JohnP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false - IMHO using return false is generally not the right thing to do. But depends on the circumstances.

Comment: @IanGrainger yup, you're right. Using `preventDefault` would just make things more consistent as the behavior of your function is predictable. I've updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This works: `<a href="test.html" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false; ">click me</a>`

However, the `onclick` attribute to attach event handlers is generally unmaintainable. The appropriate way to go about attaching the event handler depends on your javascript framework. `selector.click(function)` is appropriate in jQuery.

Comment: Please don't use (and recommend the use of) event handlers in attribute values.

Comment: Deciding on an approach to event handlers is a completely seperate subject. The author's concern is regarding `window.open`.

Comment: When providing answers to a novice, the responsible thing to do is to be pedantic about the content of the answer. If there's a better way, you should show it.

Comment: You're right. I now attempt to make the situation more clear in my answer.

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm a novice... now I know enough to get myself into **real** trouble.

Comment: With Ates on this one. Not even helping a novice, just helping anyone in general you should give them _up to date_ code. JS inline has been outdated for a _long_ time. It'd be like if someone asked how to make text move left and right for a scroller and you gave them a `<marquee>` tag as a suggestion ;)

Comment: You make a fair point -- however, `onclick` is a stylistic error, while `<marquee>` is actually deprecated. My answer was penned with an `onclick` handler simply because it takes less time to write and read.